# How to create a chart system with Date ranges like Google Analytics?

Tags: 7, datetime, charts

I want to create a chart system for my website, for the apparel trend forecasting company. To do so, I want to add trends of sales based on today, yesterday, this week, this month, and year trend.

I have created the chart, but can't find any module to solve my purpose. I tried the [Date Facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_facets) module, but I don't know why I cannot get it to work, even though I have installed the [Facet API](http://drupal.org/project/facetapi) too.

Is there any similar module to make this work?

Some more details about what I'm trying to do:

- suppose it's a chart about shirt trends.
- about these types of shirts: sleeveless, half sleeve, or full sleeve.
- filtered by Today, Yesterday, This week, This month, this year.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at the [Comparison of Charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985). Here is a quote from it:

> There are a variety of modules that facilitate the creation of charts. When it comes to charting in Drupal, the saying "There's a module for it" doesn't really apply. In this case, it's more accurate to say, "There are plenty of modules for it" ...
>
> These modules support for various charting libraries that may be desirable based on a site's desired appearance, feature-set, and licensing needs.

Using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module is one of the options to consider. Here is part of what's currently included in that link (its project page):

> Transform **Data** into **Information**. Charts are a very good way to visualize a lot of data in a way that can be quickly digested.
>
> **Features**
>
> **Wide chart type support**: Pie, Line, Bar, Column, Area or Scatter charts.
>
> **API**: A Drupal-friendly syntax for creating charts easily, regardless of the underlying library.
>
> **Views integration**: Display the Views results as charts.
>
> **Examples**: The module includes lots of example charts for you to reference when building your own charts or chart library integration.
>
> **Supported charting libraries**: out of the box, you may use either (the new) Google Charts (**GC** for short) or Highcharts  (**HC** for short) as the charting library.

For 'documentation' about the charts module, you may want to start from its [community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/233753).

There is an issue also that might be worth looking at, about [Graph node input over time (support date formatting on a continuous axis)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096). In [Comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1237096#comment-7697321) of that issue is stated: 'The trouble here is that neither Views nor Date modules provide aggregation options for date-based fields'.

Disclosure: I'm the author of the comparison (+ co-maintainer of the charts module), I hope this does not violate the site's [policy on self-promotion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: Helllllloooo sir, thanks for helping me out. But my main issue was filtering graph results based on date,  I have tried date facet module but it seems not working for me.